# appflayer deeplinking not working when application open from link (delegate method not called)

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, appsflyer

I have deeplinking with AppFlayer SDK and universal link open the application successfully means deeplinking working fine.

Now issue is that **when application open from link then it will not redirect to it's page. But if I put application in background and take in foreground then deeplinking works**

I follow this guide lines.([link](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/208874366-OneLink-Integration-Guide-Version-1-1))

*AppFlayer setup code*

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        AppsFlyerTracker.shared().appsFlyerDevKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        AppsFlyerTracker.shared().appleAppID = "xxxxxxx"
        AppsFlyerTracker.shared().isDebug = false
        AppsFlyerTracker.shared().delegate = self

        self.pushNotificationService(application)

        objStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)

        return true
    }
```

*AppFlayer delegate*

> Edit :: This method not called when application is open from link of appsflayer marketing

```
//MARK:
        //MARK: appflayer delegate
        func onAppOpenAttribution(_ installData: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        NSLog("installData ::%@", installData )

        if let link = installData["link"] as? String
        {
            if link.contains(read_Localizable("titleAppflayer"))
            {
                if let arrQueryItems = URLComponents(string: link)!.queryItems {

                    for obj in arrQueryItems {
                        if obj.name.caseInsensitiveCompare(read_Localizable("appflayerParameter")) == .orderedSame
                        {
                            self.redirectAppflayer(withstrUrl: obj.value!)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

user activity method of application

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

//        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL
//        {
//            NSLog("URL :: %@",[url])
//        }

        if userActivity.webpageURL?.absoluteString.contains(read_Localizable("titleAppflayer")) == true
        {
            AppsFlyerTracker.shared().continue(userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
            return true
        }

        return Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)
    }
```

Let me know what i doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean `.. it will not redirect to it's page.` ?

Comment: @MaximShoustin sorry my bad. I mean need to redirect at specific location

Comment: Why not use the [Branch](http://branch.io) SDK to perform the deep linking on open. You can just perform your routing in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` which I believe you should be using with AppsFlyer anyways

Comment: @clayjones94 it is my client requirement that it need appsflayer deeplinking

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the AppsFlyerTracker from `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` when it should be called from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Could you move the relevant code and test again?

Comment: I already initialise it in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but got same result

Comment: I'm assuming that you call `AppsFlyerTracker.shared().trackAppLaunch()` from `applicationDidBecomeActive` ?
&nbsp;
Also, `return Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)` returns YES if you add a breakpoint to `continueUserActivity`?
&nbsp;
There is no need for Branch integration in order to use AppsFlyer deep link capabilities.

Comment: yes i already code it in applicationDidBecomeActive and i also used branch io for sharing other thing so i need it.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
[[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker] trackAppLaunch];
```

onConversionDataSuccess method will start getting call.